# Angular Table Expansion Panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, devexpress

I'm new to angular and I can't seem to find an easy way to implement a table with an expansion slider that will contain some drop down menus.

Here is a Gif of my wireframe design (done in Javascript).

[image]

I found this Angular Materials Expansion Panel: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

It seems to want most of the data to be in the expansion panel and not in the one-line header. It won't just let me cram a whole table in there.

Has anyone got an easy solution to this? I'm using Angular 14.

My project team are really picky about adding new dependencies. We have Angular Materials and DevExpress only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my design. This was too hard. I just had a row of drop down field in the header without the fancy expand/close mechanic.

I only had to show these headers on half the tables so for those that required it I just gave them a separate CSS class that enabled the dropdowns. I used angular's *ngIf="" and [ngClass]="function()"